# How can I write a function that returns odd numbers only from a list of integers, using R language?

Tags: r, function

How can I write a function that returns odd numbers only from a list of integers, using R language?
So far I tried this

```
 function3 <- function(x){
      x<-as.integer(x)
      if (x %% 2 ==1) {
          return(x)
      }
    }
```

but it doesn't work for lists or vectors, and I don't really know how to change my code since the "if" will complain with the condition >"has length > 1" and only the first element will be used

Comment: `function(x) x[ x %% 2 == 1 ]`. Some problems with your code: if `x` is a vector then your `if` will complain with `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`, and since you do not cut out the non-odd elements, it returns the input argument. (The only change is that I'm inferring you intend it to be integerized, though you would really have needed `x <- as.integer(x)` for that.)

Comment: Thank you very much , it was a typo, and that explains the first error message. Now that my code work for single integer; I would like to use lists (vectors) and have my function returns only the odd elements of the list but I don' really know how to do so.

Comment: My comment has the answer in the first 28 characters. The only thing you need to add to it is if you need to convert to integers.

Comment: At least part of this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23316161/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14170778/3358272. Your original question of how to return odd numbers was not enough to know it was a duplicate the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
justodd <- function(x) x[ x %% 2 == 1 ]
justodd(4:20)
# [1]  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Explanation:

- Indexing is described in [`?Extract`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/Extract) (also in `?[`), you'll see that it takes either a list of `integer` (or integerizable `numeric`) or `logical`. If the former, the numbers need to be within the length of the vector; if the latter, then it should be the same length as the original vector. For example,

  ```r
  x <- 4:20
  x[c(3,5,1)]
  # [1] 6 8 4
  x[c(F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F)]
  # [1]  6  8 12
  ```
- so our `[`-insides looks like

  ```r
  x %% 2 == 1
  #  [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
  # [13] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  ```
- then we index the original vector `x` based on that return value

---

**Update**

Your mention of it not working with a `list` as an argument suggests an alternative that is slower but works on both vectors and lists.

```r
justodd2 <- function(x) Filter(function(a) a %% 2 == 1, x)
vec <- 4:20
lst <- as.list(4:20)
str(vec)
#  int [1:17] 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ...
str(lst)
# List of 17
#  $ : int 4
#  $ : int 5
#  $ : int 6
#  $ : int 7
#  $ : int 8
#  $ : int 9
#  $ : int 10
#  $ : int 11
#  $ : int 12
#  $ : int 13
#  $ : int 14
#  $ : int 15
#  $ : int 16
#  $ : int 17
#  $ : int 18
#  $ : int 19
#  $ : int 20
justodd2(vec)
# [1]  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
justodd2(lst)
# [[1]]
# [1] 5
# [[2]]
# [1] 7
# [[3]]
# [1] 9
# [[4]]
# [1] 11
# [[5]]
# [1] 13
# [[6]]
# [1] 15
# [[7]]
# [1] 17
# [[8]]
# [1] 19
```

Performance comparison:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  a = justodd(vec),
  b = justodd2(vec),
  c = justodd2(lst)
)
# Unit: nanoseconds
#  expr   min    lq  mean median    uq     max neval
#     a   800  1000 26642   1100  1200 2537700   100
#     b 12100 12500 24154  12700 13150 1055600   100
#     c 12100 12300 23777  12500 12800 1022900   100
```

(Ignore the high `mean` and `max` values from `microbenchmark`, they are often biased by garbage-collection in the R internals. If you don't know what that is ... just press the `[I believe]` button or google it.)

So ultimately, if you are always dealing with vectors, then I suggest the first `justodd` solution, otherwise the `justodd2` is safer (as `justodd(lst)` fails).