# How do I implement an if statement using a vector in a nicely documented manner?

Tags: r

I have the following function

```
FEType <- function(NoGears  ){
    ret="Low"
    if ((NoGears == 1)   ) {ret ="Med"}
    return(ret)
}
```

and I call it using

```
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(trainingdata) 
#No.Gears is an integer
df$FEType = FEType( df$No.Gears  )
```

I get

> Warning message in if ((NoGears == 1)) {: "the condition has length >
> 1 and only the first element will be used"

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316161/the-condition-has-length-1-and-only-the-first-element-will-be-used) I need to use a vector
But I am not seeing how to send a vector to my function.

Update

I was able to do the following;

```
FEType <- function(v  ){
    ret="Low"
    if ((v[1] == 1)   ) {ret ="Med"}
    return(ret)
}
```

and call it via

```
df$FEType = FEType( c(df$No.Gears)
```

The code is less than satisfying to read.
How do I do this in a more readable manner?

[Update]

One answer is to use a names vector

```
FEType <- function(v ,n  ){
   
    ret="Low"
    names(v ) <-n
    if ((v["NoGears"] == 1)   ) {ret ="Med"}
    return(ret)
}
```

I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745104/how-do-i-write-a-user-defined-function-in-r) to give context to my problem.

Comment: I assume you want `FEType <- function(NoGears) ifelse(NoGears == 1, "Med", "Low")`. Please take a look at the linked duplicate target for help with understanding the error message. I am fairly certain that this is indeed a duplicate of the linked post.

Comment: I have edited this post quite a bit, and asked a new question as well. It is not a straight out duplicate, but most likely the question has been asked somehow already.

Comment: A reproducible example makes it easier for others to help you quickly and accurately .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745336/how-do-i-write-a-function-in-r-to-do-cacluations-on-a-record

Comment: I have included an example from iris at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745336/how-do-i-write-a-function-in-r-to-do-cacluations-on-a-record